# ゲストOSからホストOSへのpingが繋がらない

Tags: network, virtualbox

現在、VirutualBoxを使ってゲストOSをインストールしてあります。環境は以下です。

●アダプターはホストオンリー
●ゲストOSはWindows10(64bit)とKali-Linuxの2つを用意
●ホストOSはWindows10(64bit)

症状ですが、ゲストOS→ゲストOS、ホストOS→ゲストOS、ゲストOS→ルーターに対してpingは通るのですが、ゲストOS → ホストOSに対してはpingが通りません。（ゲストWindows、ゲストLinuxともにホストWindowsに対してpingが通りません)

試したことは、症状からしてホストOSで受信を遮断しているのかと思い、調べながら、ホストOSのファイアーウォールの受信規則で、エコー要求の規則を有効にしましたが、ダメでした。
もしかしたら、セキュリティソフトとしてホストOSにノートンがインストールしてあるので、そのせいかとも思ったのですが、ファイアーウォールの設定画面を開いてもよくわかりませんでした^^;

ほかに心当たりのある原因や解決方法などありますでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

追記:
ゲストOSは共にアダプター2でNATネットワークも設定してあります。

Comment: ホストOSに対しpingを実行する際のIPアドレスは、ホストオンリーアダプタに設定しているIPアドレスになっていますか?

Comment: はい、ホストオンリーのIPを入力しています。ホストオンリーネットワークでのIPは、ホストOSで10.0.0.1、ゲストOSで10.0.0.2、10.0.0.3とかで、ホストOSにルーターから割り当てられるIPは192.168.〜ですが、10.0.0.1の方のpingが通らない状態です。192.168.〜の方はなぜか通ります。

Comment: ゲストOSからホストOS(`192.168.xxx.xxx`)へpingが通る、ということですので、VMにはNATネットワークが設定されており、ゲストOSはそちら経由で外部に通信できる構成と予想しました。そうであれば、質問に構成を追記した方が、回答を得られやすくなると思います。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。確認してみたらゲストOSにNATも設定してありました。編集させていただきます。

Comment: ホストWindows側のF/Wを無効にしてpingは通りますか？

Comment: windowsのファイアーウォールを無効にしても通りませんでしたが、ノートンのファイアーウォールを無効にしたら通りました。やはりセキュリティソフトが原因でした。コメントありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

問題の切り分けでF/Wが怪しいと思ったら一度無効化して試してみるのも手ですね。
それで、ノートンのF/Wを完全に無効化のままもアレだと思うので調べてみました。

1つ目は[「ルールの追加ウィザード」を使う方法](https://support.norton.com/sp/ja/jp/home/current/solutions/v1028179_ns_retail_ja_jp)で設定を行う。

2つ目は、下記の設定をお試しください。

> 1. ノートンのメインウィンドウで［設定］をクリックします。
> 2. ［設定］ウィンドウで、［ネットワーク］タブをクリックします。
> 3. ［スマートファイアウォール］を選択し、［拡張設定］の`[設定[+]]`を開きます。
> 4. ［トラフィックルール］の`[設定[+]]`を開きます。
> 5. ［デフォルト遮断インバウンド/アウトバウンド ICMP］を選択し、ウィンドウ下部の`[修正]`を選択します。
> 6. ［処理］のタブで、［許可］を選択します。
> 7. ［コンピュータ］のタブで、［ローカルサブネットにある任意のコンピュータ］を選択します。
> 8. ［OK］のボタンで各項目を保存し設定を完了します。

Comment: 解決しました。回答ありがとうございます。